# Scrapy can't find XPath content

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm writing a web crawler with Scrapy to download the text of talk-backs on a certain webpage.

Here is the relevant part of the code behind the webpage, for a specific talkback:

```
<div id="site_comment_71339" class="site_comment site_comment-even large high-rank">
    <div class="talkback-topic">
        <a class="show-comment" data-ajax-url="/comments/71339.js?counter=97&num=57" href="/comments/71339?counter=97&num=57">57. talk back title here </a>
</div>
    <div class="talkback-message"> blah blah blah talk-back message here </div>
....etc etc etc ......
```

While writing an XPath to get the the message:

```
titles = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='site_comment site_comment-even large high-rank']")
```

and later on:

```
item["title"] = titles.xpath("div[@class='talkback-message']text()").extract()
```

There's no bug, but it doesn't work. Any ideas why? I suppose I'm not writing the path correctly, but I can't find the error.

Thank you :)

The whole code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["tbk.co.il"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.tbk.co.il/tag/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95/talkbacks"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='site_comment site_comment-even large high-rank']")
        items=[]
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item["title"] = titles.xpath("div[@class='talkback-message']text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: Well, there's definitely a slash missing before the `text()` element: `"div[@class='talkback-message']/text()"`. I don't know if this will be all, though.

Comment: Thank you @MarcusRickert but the problem starts beforehand in the "titles" variable (I debugged the code with "scrapy shell", and it returns an empty string). But thanks for the comment, I guess you're right (I mean, I believe you. I don't really know how to write XPaths... ;) ).

Comment: In the URL mentioned above there is no class attribute with contents `"site_comment site_comment-even large high-rank"`. Could you double-check? Use your's browsers functionality to show the raw HTML source or use the tool `wget` to retrieve it.

Comment: @MarcusRickert, I didn't really get it... is trying the '"talkback-message"' class better? - that doesn't work either. I'm sorry if I'm making silly mistakes, I'm really new with this stuff. I'm trying to get to the talk-back message. What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much...

Answer (score 6):

Here's a snippet of the HTML page for `#site_comment_74240`

```
<div class="site_comment site_comment-even small normal-rank" id="site_comment_74240">
    <div class="talkback-topic">
        <a href="/comments/74240?counter=1&amp;num=144" class="show-comment" data-ajax-url="/comments/74240.js?counter=1&amp;num=144">144. מדיניות</a>
    </div>

    <div class="talkback-username">
        <table><tr>
            <td>קייזרמן פרדי&nbsp;</td>
            <td>(01.11.2013)</td>
        </tr></table>
    </div>
```

The "talkback-message" `div` is not in the HTML page when you first fetch it, but rather is fetched asynchronously via some AJAX query when you click on a comment title, so you'll have to fetch it for each comment.

Comment blocks, `titles` in you code snipper, can be grabbed using an XPath like this: `//div[starts-with(@id, "site_comment_"])`, i.e. all `div`s that have an "id" attribute beginning with string ""site_comment_"

You can also use CSS selectors with `Selector.css()`. In your case, you can grab comment blocks using either the "id" approach (as I've done above using XPath), so:

```
titles = sel.css("div[id^=site_comment_]")
```

or using the "site_comment" class without the other "site_comment-even", "site_comment-odd",  "small", "normal-rank" or "high-rank" that vary:

```
titles = sel.css("div.site_comment")
```

Then you would issue a new `Request` using the URL that's in `./div[@class="talkback-topic"]/a[@class="show-comment"]/@data-ajax-url` inside that comment `div`. Or using CSS selectors, `div.talkback-topic > a.show-comment::attr(data-ajax-url)` (by the way, the `::attr(...)` is not standard, but is a Scrapy extension to CSS selectors using pseudo elements functions)

What you get from the AJAX call is some Javascript code, and you want to grab the content inside `old.after(...)`

```
var old = $("#site_comment_72765");
old.attr('id', old.attr('id') + '_small');
old.hide();
old.after("\n<div class=\"site_comment site_comment-odd large high-rank\" id=\"site_comment_72765\">\n  <div class=\"talkback-topic\">\n        <a href=\"/comments/72765?counter=42&amp;num=109\" class=\"show-comment\" data-ajax-url=\"/comments/72765.js?counter=42&amp;num=109\">109. ביבי - האדם הנכון בראש ממשלת ישראל(לת)<\/a>\n    <\/div>\n   \n      <div class=\"talkback-message\">\n          \n      <\/div>\n   \n  <div class=\"talkback-username\">\n     <table><tr>\n           <td>ישראל&nbsp;<\/td>\n         <td>(11.03.2012)<\/td>\n        <\/tr><\/table>\n   <\/div>\n   <div class=\"rank-controllers\">\n      <table><tr>\n           \n          <td class=\"rabk-link\"><a href=\"#\" data-thumb=\"/comments/72765/thumb?type=up\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"/images/elements/thumbU.png?1376839523\" /><\/a><\/td>\n         <td> | <\/td>\n         <td class=\"rabk-link\"><a href=\"#\" data-thumb=\"/comments/72765/thumb?type=down\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"/images/elements/thumbD.png?1376839523\" /><\/a><\/td>\n           \n              <td> | <\/td>\n             <td>11<\/td>\n          \n      <\/tr><\/table>\n   <\/div>\n   \n      <div class=\"talkback-links\">\n            <a href=\"/comments/new?add_to_root=true&amp;html_id=site_comment_72765&amp;sibling_id=72765\">תגובה חדשה<\/a>\n            &nbsp;&nbsp;\n          <a href=\"/comments/72765/comments/new?html_id=site_comment_72765\">הגיבו לתגובה<\/a>\n         &nbsp;&nbsp;\n          <a href=\"/i/offensive?comment_id=72765\" data-noajax=\"true\">דיווח תוכן פוגעני<\/a>\n     <\/div>\n   \n<\/div>");
var new_comment = $("#site_comment_72765");
```

This is HTML data that you'll need to parse again using something `Selector(text=this_ajax_html_data)` and a `.//div[@class="talkback-message"]//text()` XPath or `div.talkback-message ::text` CSS selector

Here's a skeleton spider to get you going with these ideas:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem
import urlparse
import re


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["tbk.co.il"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.tbk.co.il/tag/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95/talkbacks"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        comments = sel.css("div.site_comment")
        for comment in comments:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            # this probably has to be fixed
            #item["title"] = comment.xpath("div[@class='talkback-message']text()").extract()

            # issue an additional request to fetch the Javascript
            # data containing the comment text
            # and pass the incomplete item via meta dict
            for url in comment.css('div.talkback-topic > a.show-comment::attr(data-ajax-url)').extract():
                yield Request(url=urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url),
                    callback=self.parse_javascript_comment,
                    meta={"item": item})
                break

    # the line we are looking for begins with "old.after"
    # and we want everythin inside the parentheses
    _re_comment_html = re.compile(r'^old\.after\((?P<html>.+)\);$')
    def parse_javascript_comment(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        # loop on Javascript content lines
        for line in response.body.split("\n"):
            matching = self._re_comment_html.search(line.strip())
            if matching:
                # what's inside the parentheses is a Javascript strings
                # with escaped double-quotes
                # a simple way to decode that into a Python string
                # is to use eval()
                # then there are these "<\/tag>" we want to remove
                html = eval(matching.group("html")).replace(r"<\/", "</")

                # once we have the HTML snippet, decode it using Selector()
                decoded = Selector(text=html, type="html")

                # and save the message text in the item
                item["message"] = u''.join(decoded.css('div.talkback-message ::text').extract()).strip()
                # and return it
                return item
```

You can try it out using `scrapy runspider tbkspider.py`.